# how do i multiply range of Long type with lambda expression

Tags: kotlin

how do i write a lambda expression that accepts two long arguments as a range borders and returns multiplication of all the numbers in this range

```
val lambda: (Long, Long) -> Long = { x, y -> for (i in x..y) {x * y}//I don't know what to fix in this block }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [reduce](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html) function, it does the operation in O(n-1):

```kotlin
val lambda: (Long, Long) -> Long = { x, y -> (x..y).reduce { a, b -> a*b } }
```

<strike>But unfortunately it'll throw an exception if there is 0 element or 1 element in the collection, so I'd suggest to use the fold function, it'll take one more iteration i.e. O(n):</strike>

```kotlin
val lambda: (Long, Long) -> Long = { x, y -> (x..y).fold(1) { a, b -> a*b } }
```

It should and will throw for elements passed as `lambda(3L, 1L)` because there were no elements, instead of 1.

Comment: I feel the `reduce` would work fine. No worries of any exception as the lamdba signature expects the 2 params and even if they are same, the range operator takes care of it.

Comment: Well you are correct it should throw an exception instead of returning 1 because there were no elements.

Comment: The range problem should be handled separately. Coz if you pass `lambda(3L, 1L)`, with the `fold(1)` implementation it would return 1, which would not be the right way to handle exception scenario.